# Tag synonyms system not working on migrated question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms

On SF, the tag [network](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=network) is remapped to [networking](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=networking). This is since July 16 (done by Kyle).
Now take a look to https://serverfault.com/questions/161850/unable-to-connect-to-the-remote-server migrated from SO to SF after July 16. It's tagged with network.
So I guess the synonyms code to not be run when question are migrated.

Here is something else, I did not test but when you migrate a question from site X to site  Y what's append if there was a synonyms on site X but not site Y?
I see two way to implement synonyms system:

1. The job is done when displaying the page. If this were the case, my question taken as example should be OK on SF, so I guess this is not the current implementation.
2. The job is done when submitting the question. In this latter case, imagine a question tagged ips-firewall on SO, SO communities focus on programming so they don't care about firewall and decided to make ips-firewall, ids-firewall, firewall synonyms. The question on SO will be tagged firewall and so when migrated to SF still tagged firewall while it would be better to have it tagger ips-firewall on SF because SF take care of the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design at the moment; the tags on the parent site may not even exist at all on the child site.

So other than stripping out "belongs-on-sitename" / moderator-only tags, and other such obvious problems, we don't touch the tags in a migration.

Answer (score 1):

Tag synonyms will be checked during question migration.