# Use tag synonyms when migrating questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, tag-synonyms

<sub>[Note: I know this question is similar to [Tag synonyms system not working on migrated question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59255/tag-synonyms-system-not-working-on-migrated-question), but its answer doesn't answer *this* question.]</sub>

Over at Apple.SE, we've just started getting migrated questions, and that's caused things to get a little funky. Here's an example:

- We currently have the tag `[podcasts]`, which has a synonym of `[podcast]`.
- A question with the tag `[podcast]` on its source site gets chosen for migration.
- When the question is imported, the `[podcast]` tag ignores that it's a synonym and gets added to the tag db.
- We end up with something that's both a tag *and* a synonym.

**Request**: When applicable, tags on imported questions should be rewritten to their synonyms, just as if the question had been asked directly.

I'm not asking that anything be done about new tags; those aren't a problem. This is about tags for which we've already got synonyms, where ignoring those synonyms gets messy and causes extra work for mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great suggestion! This will be pushed tonight.