# Split Tag merging from Tag renaming

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-merge-utility

The UI for merging tags can also be used to **rename** tags.  As I understand it, it works something like this:

- There is a Master tag Textbox and a Remove/Rename Tag textbox.
- If the Remove/Rename Tag exists, it will be merged into the Master Tag.
- If the Remove/Rename Tag does not exist, the Master Tag will be renamed.

## Wat.

These are two completely different functions--merging and renaming.  They should be split within the UI because [this dual behavior is not clear at all.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87999/bug-in-the-merge-tags-ui)

I would strongly suggest the two functions be split.

Comment: Related request: [suggesting that the Master Tag remain the destination tag even if it doesn't exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75287/change-tag-renaming-to-be-more-consistent).

Answer (score 4):

This page always confused me ... I went ahead and simplified

[image: new ui]

Simple, there is old, there is new ... old will be gone, new will be created (if it is missing).

Comment: That's a *little* better.  I still say two completely separate forms would be a better idea.  You can host them on the same page, have them post to two different methods.  But this is an improvement, thanks.

Comment: @Will what is the point? both screens would perform the same function? old state is gone, new state exists.

Comment: The point is to separate two completely different functions into two completely different web forms.  Dunno, seems pretty simple and obvious to me.  Renaming =/= creating synonyms.  Why try to combine the two in the same form?  I've seen the page; there is plenty of real estate.  Hell, I think you guys could even spare another page entirely for one or the other...

Comment: @Will I am talking spanish and you are talking french here .... now I follow .... THE BIG issue was that the old UI used to do what appeared to be random stuff, the confusing rename/remove dialog flipped what it would do based on tag counts, which was horribly confusing... as to synonyms, this is on purpose here for very good reason. If you ever want to create a synonym you are responsible for merging the old mess... otherwise we get this pain is never going to end http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest