# Blacklisted tags on migrated questions prevent users from suggesting edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, suggested-edits, blocked-tags

When I tried to suggest an edit to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/2d-zelda-collision-detection), I got an error message telling me that I can't create new tags when I was not.

When I removed the **[game-development]**, which is blacklisted on GameDev, the problem went away.

As I understand it, when the question was migrated from Stack Overflow to GameDev, the question was not stripped of its game-development tag. However, since it's blacklisted, the site ignored it. As far the site was concerned, there were only four tags on the question, not five.

So, when I tried to edit the question, the site believed I was trying to create the **[game-development]** tag even though it was there since before I came to edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are planning to add logic that looks at the tags on a question as it is migrated.

- If any of the tags do not exist on the destination site, they will be deleted from the question during migration.
- If none of the tags exist on the destination site, the question will be closed as off-topic on the original site and will not be migrated.

This will prevent tags being created through the back door during migration and clear up issues with later edits to the question.

Comment: any chance of also auto-translating synonyms, as I suggested at [Use tag synonyms when migrating questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73290/use-tag-synonyms-when-migrating-questions)? (oh please, oh please…)

Comment: This will be pushed tonight.

Comment: And @Dori - YOUR WISH HAS BEEN GRANTED :)

Comment: @Jarrod - can I have a pony? :-D (and thanks!)

Comment: @Dori of course http://goo.gl/VlUKF

Comment: @Jarrod - “[pony tomorrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_tomorrow), and pony yesterday, but never pony today…”

Comment: One problem I see with this: Most LaTeX related questions are only tagged with [tag:latex] on SO or SU. That tag doesn't exist on TeX.SX. So every migrated question will just get closed?

Comment: +1, but I'm curious about your resopnse to Caramdir's question. Also, what kind of notification(s) do(es) the OP/closers get? I ask because I wonder what would happen to [this guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78883/where-is-the-right-place-to-post-questions-about-orcaflex-a-marine-modeling-soft/78885#78885).

Comment: @PopularDemand, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/926/problematic-migration-change/930#930

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. (@Reb)