# Where is the right place to post questions about OrcaFlex, a marine modeling software package?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I use a software package called [OrcaFlex](http://orcina.com/SoftwareProducts/OrcaFlex/index.php) for modeling marine structures.  It has extensions in MATLAB, Python, and C (I use MATLAB) that are used for setting up the models and retrieving and analyzing the model results.   Setting up the models requires a lot of tricky choices that would be nice to discuss with others, but the only choice is emailing the (very helpful) support staff, or posting questions to the software developer's blog.  Is there a place on Stack Overflow or related sites that would be an appropriate place start posting questions about use of OrcaFlex?  Or is the software too specific to marine engineering?   There are no existing OrcaFlex questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There's nowhere on the stack exchange network that has people who can answer your OrcaFlex questions. It's just too specialised. Your best bet is just to e-mail us at Orcina and we'll answer your questions. I'd quite like to start a Stack Overflow type site specifically for OrcaFlex users.

Comment: It would be fabulous if you were to start an OrcaFlex forum. I think you would see an uptick in users' learning speed. I tend to have the same problems and use OrcaFlex just infrequently enough that I re-make the same mistakes. Having a forum would make it easier for me to retain the knowledge.

Comment: I've thought for a while that our own Stack Overflow type site dedicated to OrcaFlex use would be valuable. In order to make it happen, we'd need to choose either a hosted service, or one of the gazillion Stack Exchange clones to use. A lot of the user support we do would be valuable to a wider audience than just the individual that asks one specific question. It's certainly something that we are considering.

Comment: It is a really good idea to create an OrcaFlex forum. I'm working with this fantastic software now, and I'm very excited to get to know better how to use it. @DavidHeffernan, I could see you are the Software Development Director at Orcina, so probably you can help me with my question... is that possible to create plug-ins for real time interaction with the user in OrcaFlex, either using one of those OrcFxAPIs or any other code, software, etc.?

Comment: @ramon we can certainly help but it's best if you go through our normal support channels. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange, KAE! If you're doing programming of some kind, like improving the code of OrcaFlex itself or developing a plugin, then use Stack Overflow. If you're just trying to figure out how to better use the program, try [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

We won't consider your question unacceptable for being "too specific to marine engineering" (or any given field), but if there are no other OrcaFlex users visiting our sites, you may not get answers.