# Cross referencing tags across different Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, tags, cross-site-tags

I was wondering if it would make sense to cross reference the tags we have for questions on different Stack Exchange sites. Some examples would be like the tags of "cosmology" and "astrophysics" which would be relevant to both astronomy and physics. Similarly there would be questions relating to astrophotography which might be relevant to the Photography community and its Stack Exchange website. (The examples relate to astronomy because that's the Stack Exchange site I have most experience with. I'm sure you could think of many more examples).

I can imagine that this would be an administrative hassle at some level, but maybe it's worth figuring out a way to unify across "different" "subjects". We could also have some aspects of user ratings independent of subject. Someone who contributes a lot in one field will definitely have a good handle on a related question in a different field. Such steps will increase interaction and bring in experts from neighbouring and related fields into a community. After all, knowledge is unified and we split it into different fields quite arbitrarily.

Answer (score 6):

Keep in mind that there are also tags that you *don't* want converted.

- [canon](/questions/tagged/canon) means drastically different things on, say, SciFi.se versus SU or Photography.se.
- [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) and [java](/questions/tagged/java) mean different things on SO versus Cooking.se
- and so on…

Comment: Yes, but I would imagine that community moderators could manually approve/disapprove this cross-linking. All that's needed is for SE to have a facility where such linking can be manually enabled. 
Further, it would be great if there could be automated suggestions, but that's a different module and such functionality can always be tweaked once we see what works in practice.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice to have tags mapped between sites so that if a question is migrated it picks up the right tags.

Comment: So long as a tag doesn't show up on a site unless there are questions on that site using that tag.

Comment: @squillman, well, that's what they do right now, I just want the ones that can be mapped mapped, not sure what to do with new tags.

Comment: All that's required to make this happen is to add a whole lotta synonyms. If you do that, questions migrated in with tag "a" are automatically converted to tag "b" during the migration.

Comment: @Dori, yep, that would do the trick, as long as synonyms convert when migrated.

Comment: [and they do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73290/use-tag-synonyms-when-migrating-questions)!

Answer (score 0):

Can I endorse the OP's question, especially as some of the original technical communities fragment. I am interested in software signal processing for electrical control systems using MATLAB so my questions could (I would say should) usually be asked equally validly in all three communities, unless tags cross sites. Perhaps moderators could add a *shared with site x attribute* to tags (or not in the cases identified by @Dori) perhaps as suggested in the meta sites. This would be like the existing *related tags* list, i.e. *related site (for tag)*.